# Ler um arquivo texto e separar conteúdo em variáveis

Tags: c, arquivo, variáveis, estrutura-de-dados, grafo

Estou com uma dúvida em como dividir informações de um arquivo de texto em variáveis em C.
Exemplo, eu tenho um arquivo txt com os seguintes dados:

```
3 2
A
D
E
AD
DE
```

Gostaria de ler esse arquivo, e separar cada informação em uma variável, por exemplo, o número 3 em uma variável, o 2 em outra, A em outra e assim por diante, as letras juntas podem estar em um variável apenas.

Até agora o que eu consegui em termos de código foi isso:

```
void ler_arquivo(){
    int vertices;
    int arestas;
    FILE *arq = fopen("init.txt","r");
    if(arq != NULL){
        printf("\tSucesso!\n");
        char linha[3];
        while(!feof(arq)){
            fgets(linha,3,arq);
            printf("%s",linha);
        }
    }
}
```

Por enquanto estou apenas printando o vetor, porque não sei como fazer a divisão em variáveis.

Comment: Pesquise pela função strtok de <string.h>.

Comment: [cppreference.com - strtok](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exemplo incompleto (não está guardando os vértices e as arestas).
Mostra como usar a função fscanf para ler campos de um arquivo texto.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // para exit

int main()
{
  int vertices;
  int arestas;

  int nCposLidos;  // para fscanf
  char buffer[10]; // para fscanf

  int i; // para for


  FILE *arq = fopen("init.txt","r");
  if (arq == NULL)
  {
    printf("* erro na abertura do arquivo\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  // lendo vertices
  nCposLidos = fscanf(arq, "%d", &vertices);
  if (nCposLidos != 1)
  {
    printf("* erro %d na leitura do numero de vertices\n", nCposLidos);
    exit(1);
  }

  printf("* numero de vertices: %d\n", vertices);

  // lendo arestas
  nCposLidos = fscanf(arq, "%d", &arestas);
  if (nCposLidos != 1)
  {
    printf("* erro %d na leitura do numero de arestas\n", nCposLidos);
    exit(1);
  }

  printf("* numero de arestas: %d\n", arestas);

  // lendo nomes dos vertices, 1 por linha

  for (i = 0; i < vertices; i++)
  {
    nCposLidos = fscanf(arq, " %s", buffer);
    if (nCposLidos != 1)
    {
      printf("* erro %d na leitura de um vertice\n", nCposLidos);
      exit(1);
    }
    printf("* vertice lido: %s\n", buffer);
  }

  // lendo nomes das arestas, 1 por linha

  for (i = 0; i < arestas; i++)
  {
    nCposLidos = fscanf(arq, " %s", buffer);
    if (nCposLidos != 1)
    {
      printf("* erro %d na leitura de uma aresta\n", nCposLidos);
      exit(1);
    }
    printf("* aresta lida: %s\n", buffer);
  }

}
```